# Is it possible to make a connection from Android to Sql server using JDBC with integrated security?

Tags: android, jdbc, integrated-security

I am new to Android.

I have a problem, when I want to connect Android to SQL Server. On this line:

> con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);

I get an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/ietf/jgss/GSSManager;

Has anybody an idea how to solve it? And is it possible to make the "integratedSecurity=true" for Android?
Thank you.

My code:

```
 try {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        String ip = "xx.xx.xx.xxx";

        String ConnURL= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";databasename=C_Teile;integratedSecurity=true;";


        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();



        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        Log.e("ASK","Connection Called");

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("ASK","EX" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android for all kinds of reasons (security, performance, etc), and in this case the driver is using a class included in normal Java that is not available on Android.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It will be used just for intern application, for 2 users.

Comment: Then the second part of my comment still applies. JDBC drivers are developed for Java and its runtime API, so they may use features not available on Android.

Comment: but the method DriverManager.getConnection(some String) is also here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/DriverManager#getConnection(java.lang.String)

Comment: That Google included that part of the Java API in Android does not mean it is a good idea to use it, nor an indication that all JDBC drivers will work on Android.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for your responces. Does it mean, is it not possible with the feaure integratedSecurity=true?

Comment: Clearly not, because it is using the class `org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager` which is part of standard Java, but not part of Android.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel: You were right. The debugger shows an error, somethig like "on Windows only" I have used the OkHttp client and made the Sql queries in a php script. Thanks.